# access files outside public_html folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, host

I want to make some folder out of root directory (`public_html`).
I have shared server `linux` with follow directory.

- /home/`mysite`

  - access-log
  - etc
  - mail
  - public_ftp
  - `public_html`
  - `tmp`
  - `www`

and my site directory in my computer(`wamp`):

- app

  - model
  - controller
  - view
- config
- public

  - images
  - `css`
  - `js`
  - `index.php`
- `htaccess`

I want public folder to be placed into `public_html` folder in server.
1)how can I include my code using relative paths?

and I have `htaccess` file that points all requests to that `public/index.php` in my computer.

2)Where should I put my `htaccess` in my Shared server `linux`?

my `htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: `.htaccess` acts like a `<Directory>` directive. Put the .htaccess file in the directory where you want the overrides to occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need place all public file in public_html.
2. Move .htaccess to public html (that example not redirect to public/html only redirect to index.php and is fine)
3. if have absoulute path example "../public" change to "../public_html", if is relative path is fine
4. Move all other not public code in root folder.

You aplication must be running in this time.

Answer (score 0):

Put everything in

> /home/mysite

and configure your virtual host to use

> /home/mysite/public/

as DocumentRoot.
Put the .htaccess in

> /home/mysite/public/

Comment: i put content of public folder into public_html folder , is it correct?

Comment: If you put it in the "public"-folder, you hast have to reconfigure your VirtualHost, which is easier than reconfiguring everything to use "public_html" instead of "public".

Answer (score 0):

You can't traverse out of the document root using relative paths or rewriting in the htaccess file. You *can* include files from your php script (`index.php`). So what you can do is allow a request for something outside of `public_html` to be routed to `index.php`, then in php, load the file outside of `public_html`.